# how to replace a pixel with a set of pixel c#

Tags: c#, image, graphics

hi i'm making photo mosaic creator but i can't replace a pixel with a set of pixel if any one know how to do this in c# please help cause i'm beginner in c#

and i understand the idea but i can't implement in c#

the idea is we have a input photo and we have a data set of small photos and we create  an empty output photo and we put inside here the small photo from the data set after we take the pixel average RBG color from the input photo and we take the average RBG color of the small photo then we replace the pixel with the photo that have the same RGB color of the pixel and sort the small photo's in the output photo

Comment: Sounds good, what did you try and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you don't "replace a pixel with an entire picture" when building a mosaic digitally.  Instead, you create a brand new output image that is *much* larger than the input.  Then you think about a grid on the output so that each input pixel corresponds to a grid square in the output.  You then copy an image into each grid square, checking the corresponding input pixel to find out what image is appropriate.

Comment: ok that is good but i don,t  know how to do that in c# can you please send a link for that or a source code

Comment: @user2440284: I don't plan to do your project for you.  But I will give you hints to get you moving when you are stuck.  For right now, you could think about how big the output image should be, and knowing that "create something" means constructing an object, you could look through the C# documentation and find out what class is good for representing an photo.

Comment: ok now i have better understand of the project in this we need four function : 

the first to determine the each pixel color of the input image so the input of the function is string (the path of the image ) and the output (the pixels colors)

the second is hash table or some kind of list the input is the (the pixel colors) and the output is (an integer each integer represent a color)

Comment: third function for the dataset of the small images that we will use and after we calculate the average color for every image in  the dataset we assign an integer number for every image and that number will be represent the average color of the image  then we save the integer number in list and we make this operation om time and save the result is a file

Comment: fourth function that take the output of the second function as input and make a search operation to find the equivalent number in the file from the third function 
and then we sort those number in array taht have the size of the input image size multiply by the size of one of the small images from the dataset 
so can u help me :D

Answer (score 0):

I have not used it, but [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) is a class for creating bitmaps and has a `SetPixel` method.